# How to totally disable swipe back on Android phone?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gesture, touch-event

Gestures are common operatons while playing games , if players swipe right from the edge of the screen, The screen goes back to previous screen and the game will be paused (or over).

The following code can stop going back, but the swipe gesture first causes `onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent)` to be cancelled and stops the operation the players want to do, it's not a good experience for players.

Is there a better idea to disable the back gesture?

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   // super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the statement whether user playing.

For example;

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(!isPlaying){
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

and so on.
I hope, this will help you :)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it will still cancel the player's touch event while playing game.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use setOnKeyListener to listen all hardware keys.

For this Hardware Back Button equals to `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`

So the code can be like in this example;

```
view.apply {
            isFocusableInTouchMode = true
            requestFocus()

            setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Hardware Back Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                true // If this is true then it will not send to onBackPressed() otherwise it will send
            }
        }
```

The point is return value. If it is true then it will not call onBackPressed() otherwise it will call onBackPressed().

view equals to Fragment.view or view of onViewCreated() parameter.

So you can read all the time if any key pressed with these function, you can send return value according to your needs.

Comment: Actually the code does the same thing as the above, I had also tried method `override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean`. On android,  When player swipe from the screen edge left to right, player's operation will be stopped while a left arrow shows up. I'm looking for a setting to disable this default detection like iOS does.